# Is "What do you know" the same as "You know what"

Tags: meaning

Is "What do you know?" the same as "You know what?" If It is different, How to different?

### effort

- I tried Google Search(in [Japanese](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=you+know+what+%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3&oq=you+know&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39l2j0j69i60j69i61.2737j0j4)))
- keyword - `You know what means` and `different from you know what and what do you know`

  - I searched the keyword in Japanese without "You know what" and "What do you know".

after that, I knew:

- "You know what" means

  - How to use

but I did not know "What do you know" means and how to different.

---

Please teaching of that. Thank you.

Comment: Related / Duplicate: [What is the meaning of “Well, what do you know” here in The Dark Knight Rises?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10704/)

Comment: You definitely did add **effort** in your question, didn't you? LOL as they say :) For users, read the edit history

Comment: Try editing the title to: Is [**"What do you know?"**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22What+do+you+know%3F%22) the same as [**"You know what"**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22You+know+what%3F%22)? Use inverted commas / quotation marks  ( " ) to "close" the phrase, and then Google only the exact phrase. Read the results on the top page, compare the usage and meaning and [*Bob's your uncle*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22Bob%27s+your+uncle%22)

Comment: Your edits are not what we mean by including your efforts (although, it's a good first step). We mean, include what you found, compare them, and explain what you found confusing when you compared them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You know what?* is an informal sentence used to indicate that one is going to say something interesting or surprising.

> You know what? I believe her.

*What do you know?* is a North American informal sentence used as an expression of surprise.

Examples and definitions are taken from the *New Oxford American Dictionary*, the application running on macOS Sierra, *Copyright © 2010, 2016 by Oxford University Press, Inc. All rights reserved*.

Answer (score 0):

"What do you know" can be used two ways.

First, as an expression of surprise.  "Well, what do you know?  That old car actually works."

Or as an actual question - the subject is implied or given by context. "Hi Bob, we were just discussing how to fix broken furniture.  What do you know?" (about the subject)

"You know what" seems similar to the first usage of "What do you know", but it's actually not.  The speaker isn't surprised at all - it's the same sense as a rhetorical question.